# R shiny - cannot find filepath of fileupload

Tags: r, shiny

I am having an issue in R shiny where the app is not able to find the the temp file. I have tried another package xlsx to try and read the file but it gives a similar error

UI
`fileInput("Tested_Sample","Upload sample test results")`

server

> evalData<-reactive({ evalQuery<- readNamedRegionFromFile(input$Tested_Sample$datapath, "Full_Query", header=FALSE)
>     return(evalData)
>   })

Error:

> Error: FileNotFoundException (Java): File '0.xlsx' could not be found - you may specify to automatically create the file if not existing.```

Comment: Does the file `0.xlsx` exists your working directory (type `getwd()` to know). Do you work in a R project (with a `.Rproj` file) ?

Comment: There was something weird going on with this input . I created another one to do the same thing at it worked but this was in a rendetable. I found that it didn't work within eventreactive. Don't know why though